# nginx 301 redirect not working

Tags: redirect, nginx

Here is my config file:

```
    server {
    listen   80;
    server_name moule-a-manque.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myvps.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myvps.com.error.log;
    client_max_body_size 4M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    expires off;

rewrite http://www.moule-a-manque.com http://moule-a-manque.com permanent;

    location / {
    root   /var/www/mom;
    index index.html index.php;
    }
```

I assumed that should work but when i check at http://nibbler.silktide.com/reports/moule-a-manque.com it seems to say that the redirect is not working.

Am i doing this ocrrectly ? If so how can make sure the 301 redirect is indeed working

Comment: Your nginx is set up to serve "moule-a-manque.com" but you are sending your test to "nibbler.silktide.com". You need to sort this basic issue out first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite directive in nginx only matches the path part of the url, not the hostname.  It looks like you're trying to force no-www, which is accomplished by using a second server{}:

```
server {
  server_name www.moule-a-manque.com;
  rewrite ^ http://moule-a-manque.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen   80;
  server_name moule-a-manque.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/myvps.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/myvps.com.error.log;
  client_max_body_size 4M;
  client_body_buffer_size 128k;
  expires off;

  root   /var/www/mom;
  index index.html index.php;
}
```

In addition, it's generally better to set your root outside of a location.  Please see http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls.